# Return data from Common Table Expression in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to return some data I have from Common Table Expression to my backend but unable to because Postgres doesn't see the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION request(
    question_id_func INTEGER,
    requester_account_id_func INTEGER,
    counter_func NUMERIC
) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$ 

  with notif AS (
     INSET INTO notification(...) VALUES (...) RETURNING *
  )
UPDATE question....
RETURN (SELECT notif_id FROM notif); 

END $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

Does anyone has a better idea how you can extract the data from CTE and return it? 
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put your UPDATE statement into a CTE, and then assign the output to a function variable using a final SELECT statement.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION request(
    question_id_func INTEGER,
    requester_account_id_func INTEGER,
    counter_func NUMERIC
) RETURNS INTEGER AS $body$ 

DECLARE
  result integer;

BEGIN
  WITH notif AS (
    INSERT INTO notification(...) VALUES (...) RETURNING *
  ),
  question_update AS (
    UPDATE question....
  )
  SELECT notif.notif_id INTO result FROM notif;

  RETURN result;

END $body$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```